# Print Report from JasperReports Server Repository

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror, jasperserver

I would like ask your help for some solutions.
I want to know how can I print report from jasperserver repository.
I spent time googling for a period of time, but still cannot get it solve.
I got this source, but it does not work. Can someone fix it?
Any idears? Please help me.

1.Here is the source code:

```
package com.src.report;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.xml.domain.impl.ResourceDescriptor;
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.irplugin.JServer;
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.irplugin.wsclient.WSClient;

public class PrintService {

    private static JServer server = null;

    public static void ConnectionString(String webServiceUrl, String username, String password){
        server = new JServer();
        server.setUsername(username);
        server.setPassword(password);
        server.setUrl(webServiceUrl);
    }

    public static void runReports(String webServiceUrl, String username, String  password) throws Exception{
        ConnectionString(webServiceUrl, username, password);
        WSClient client = new WSClient(server);

        ResourceDescriptor resourceDescriptor = new ResourceDescriptor();
        resourceDescriptor.setUriString ("/reports/samples/EmployeeAccounts");
        Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameterMap.put("MY_PARAMETER_NAME", "myparametervalue");
        JasperPrint printer = client.runReport(resourceDescriptor, parameterMap);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(printer, false, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       String webServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/services/repository";
       String username = "jasperadmin";
       String password = "jasperadmin";
       runReports(webServiceUrl, username, password);
    }
}
```

2.And here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractDOMParser
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.irplugin.wsclient.WSClient.<init>(WSClient.java:73)
at com.src.report.PrintService.runReports(PrintService.java:37)
at com.src.report.PrintService.main(PrintService.java:51)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Comment: if you update the question with the error message that you get (or if no error message then the problem as you see it) it will be easier for us to help you. Brgds, Rob

Comment: @Rob Kielty, I already update question. Any ideas? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

u can make use of the rest api of jasper
it is as simple as:

`http://<host>:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reports/pathofReport/reportID.format?j_username=username&j_password=password`

[Refer to this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v550/running-report)

Answer (score 1):

As I googled for a period of time, I have found some solution related to my question above. My purpose here is not for reputation or anything else, but just wanna tell someone who get the same issue as I did.

My solution is here:

1/ Requirement Jar Files:

1. activation-1.1.jar
2. axis-1.3.jar
3. activation-1.1.jar axis-1.3.jar
4. commons-codec-1.5.jar
5. commons-collections-3.2.jar
6. commons-digester-1.7.jar
7. commons-discovery-0.4.jar
8. commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
9. commons-logging-1.1.3-javadoc.jar
10. commons-logging-1.1.3-sources.jar
11. commons-logging-adapters-1.1.3.jar
12. commons-logging-api-1.1.3.jar
13. jasperreports-5.2.0.jar
14. jasperserver-common-ws-5.2.0.jar
15. jasperserver-ireport-plugin-2.0.1.jar
16. jaxrpc.jar
17. mail-1.4.jar
18. saaj.jar
19. wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

2/ Coding:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package jaspersoft.src.jasperprint;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.irplugin.JServer;

import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.xml.domain.impl.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporterParameter;

/**
*
* @author Administrator
*/

public class JasperPrintTest {

private static JServer server = null;

public JasperPrintTest(String webServiceUrl, String username, String password){

    server = new JServer();
    server.setUsername(username);
    server.setPassword(password);
    server.setUrl(webServiceUrl);
}

public List list(String uri) throws Exception{
    ResourceDescriptor rd = new ResourceDescriptor();
    rd.setWsType(ResourceDescriptor.TYPE_FOLDER);
    rd.setUriString(uri);
    return server.getWSClient().list(rd);
}

public ResourceDescriptor get(String uri) throws Exception{
   return get(uri, null);
}

public ResourceDescriptor get(String uri, List arg) throws Exception{

   ResourceDescriptor rd = new ResourceDescriptor();
   rd.setWsType(ResourceDescriptor.TYPE_REPORTUNIT);
   rd.setUriString(uri);
   return server.getWSClient().get(rd, null,arg);
}


public JasperPrint runReports(String reportUnit, Map params) throws Exception{
   ResourceDescriptor rd = new ResourceDescriptor();
   rd.setWsType(ResourceDescriptor.TYPE_REPORTUNIT);
   rd.setUriString(reportUnit);
   return server.getWSClient().runReport(rd, params);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String webServiceUrl="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/services/repository";
    String username= "jasperadmin";
    String password = "jasperadmin";
    String printer = "Foxit Reader PDF Printer";
    String reporturi = "/reports/samples/AllAccounts";


    JasperPrintTest object = new JasperPrintTest(webServiceUrl,username,password);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = new JasperPrint();
    Map parameterMap = new HashMap();
    try {
        jasperPrint = object.runReports(reporturi, parameterMap);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClassForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    PrintService printService = null;
    for(PrintService ps : printServices){
        if(ps.getName().equals(printer)){
            printService = ps;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(printService !=null)
    {
        JRExporter jrExporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        jrExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        jrExporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, printService);
        jrExporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, 
                printService.getAttributes());
        jrExporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        jrExporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
        try {
            jrExporter.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Printer is not defined");
    }
}
}
```

3/ Result:

[image]

Note: but everything is still not dynamic. Please notice.